# Is there any relationship between the Riemann z function and strange attractors?

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I have this question in mind since the first time I saw a graphical representation of the zeta function (like in the sample below). Just by looking to them I wondered if there is any relationship between the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_Hardy.E2.80.93Littlewood_conjectures) as showed in the sample and [strange attractors](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Strange_attractor)? Disclaimer: my question is just based in the visual look of both structures.

For instance the Lorenz's strange attractor looks like this (sorry I do not know how to reduce the size of the images):

[image]

And a graphic of the zeta function for ($\frac{1}{2}+it$) looks like this:

[image]

I have been trying to find any reference regarding Riemann zeta function and attractors but if I am not wrong there is nothing and probably this is just a visual similarity but without any real background behind. Thank you!

**UPDATE 2015/05/26**

So far I have found some papers and some hints, but nothing clear about this yet! Here is the list:

1. "Magic Angle Precession and the Riemann Zeta Function" (Binder): [The Riemann zeta function and the magic angle precession strange attractor are related by  their  functional  equations](http://www.quanics.com/mapzeta.pdf).
2. [Recurrent Anholonomy in Curved Space Navigation Solved by the Riemann Zeta Function](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1875389211005839) (Binder).

Comment: Concerning iterations and fractals you may enjoy [this](http://www.dhushara.com/DarkHeart/geozeta/zetageo.htm) (probably not an answer to your question but neat!)

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni, thank you for the reference! it is really interesting, I had a look to it, I guess I will need a weekend to read it slowly. :)

Comment: Two more things you may enjoy : the [universality of zeta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality) and the related paper by Woon ["Riemann zeta function is a fractal"](http://arxiv.org/abs/chao-dyn/9406003). Fine reading,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known relation. But there exist so called "dynamical zeta functions". I have newer seen anybody drawing plots like yours for them but maybe they look similar.

[Ref: Lagarias, about Number Theory Zeta Functions and Dynamical Zeta Functions (pdf)](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/numberthzeta.pdf)

Comment: thanks for the reference. I have added to your explanation (hope will be updated in some minutes) a link to: Number Theory Zeta Functions and Dynamical Zeta Functions, http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~lagarias/doc/numberthzeta.pdf (Lagarias)